# Python doctest error. OSX

Tags: python

I have MBP13'R running the latest OSX.

For some reason I can't run doctest...

Python code:

```
def area_tri(base, height):
    """
    >>>area_tri(10, 10)
    50
    """
    return base / 2 * height

import doctest

doctest.testmod()
```

Error message:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/name/Documents/doctest.py", line 8, in <module>
    import doctest
  File "/Users/name/Documents/doctest.py", line 9, in <module>
    doctest.testmod()
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'testmod'
```

I only just started programming on my Mac and I can't fix it...
Python version is 3.3.4

Comment: What's your python version?

Comment: Python version is 3.3.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file naming is confusing the interpreter. You've named your file `"/Users/name/Documents/doctest.py"` which has the same name as the `doctest` module.

Change the name and try again (make sure you remove the old `doctest.pyc` as well).

Demo:

Your code breaks as expected:

```
msvalkon@Lunkwill:/tmp$ python doctest.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "doctest.py", line 8, in <module>
    import doctest
  File "/tmp/doctest.py", line 9, in <module>
    doctest.testmod()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'testmod'
```

After renaming and removing the `.pyc`

```
msvalkon@Lunkwill:/tmp$ mv doctest.py dtest.py 
msvalkon@Lunkwill:/tmp$ rm doctest.pyc
msvalkon@Lunkwill:/tmp$ python dtest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dtest.py", line 9, in <module>
    doctest.testmod()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/doctest.py", line 1885, in testmod
    for test in finder.find(m, name, globs=globs, extraglobs=extraglobs):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/doctest.py", line 900, in find
    self._find(tests, obj, name, module, source_lines, globs, {})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/doctest.py", line 954, in _find
    globs, seen)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/doctest.py", line 942, in _find
    test = self._get_test(obj, name, module, globs, source_lines)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/doctest.py", line 1026, in _get_test
    filename, lineno)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/doctest.py", line 645, in get_doctest
    return DocTest(self.get_examples(string, name), globs,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/doctest.py", line 659, in get_examples
    return [x for x in self.parse(string, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/doctest.py", line 621, in parse
    self._parse_example(m, name, lineno)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/doctest.py", line 679, in _parse_example
    self._check_prompt_blank(source_lines, indent, name, lineno)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/doctest.py", line 766, in _check_prompt_blank
    line[indent:indent+3], line))
ValueError: line 2 of the docstring for __main__.area_tri lacks blank after >>>: '>>>area_tri(10, 10)'
```

Notice that you are not following `doctest` rules but this is another problem.